# listing files and folders of svn repository in c#

Tags: c#, svn

I'm trying to list all files and folders recursively under a given folder in svn using the org.tmatesoft.svn.core library in c#. I'm trying to use the getDir() function and put an iterator on the collection object. But I'm not able to access individuals objects in the collection.
Is this the way to go about it?
Or is there another cleaner way of doing it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it..
I used the getDir() function and the put the result in a Collection object. I then converted it to an array and accessed the individual items of the array as a string..
If anyone has better ideas, please let me know.